# How to achieve this kind of a design in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, mobile-application

how can I make this design in Flutter with those curves: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMZrQ.png. I was wondering if I should use a clipath or a stack widget. Because the elements are on top of each other. It is kind of confusing, because on the one side the white widget is on the back one and on the other side, the black widget is on the white one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Hopefully, you meant this design:

```
class _SingInScreenState extends State<SingInScreen> {
double height;
double width;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
  width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: height * .4,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.black,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(50),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          height: height * .6,
          color: Colors.black,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
              ),
            ),
            height: height * .5,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

}

Comment: perfect, thanks bro. Never though about having 3 containers. Nice Idea, works perfectly